# Create disk on Kubernetes without gcloud

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I'm following the Spring Cloud Data Flow "Getting Started" guide here (section 13): http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_deploying_streams_on_kubernetes

I'm new to cloud computing, and I'm stuck at at the point where I should create a disk for a MySQL DB via gcloud:

```
gcloud compute disks create mysql-disk --size 200 --type pd-standard
```

Well, that throws:

```
The required property [project] is not currently set.
```

There is one thing that I quite don't understand yet (not my main question): Gcloud requires me to register a project un my google account. I wonder how my Google account (and cloud project there), the to-be-created disk image and the server are related to each another. How does this all relate to another?

Though my actual question is, how can I create the disk for the master sserver locally without using gcloud? Because I don't want a cloud server connected to my account on google.

Comment: Where did you create your k8s cluster? You'd want to provision storage on that particular platform, not necessarily on GKE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes does not manage any remote storage on its own. You can manage local storage by mounting an `emptyDir` volume.

Gcloud creates cloud bloc storage on your Google cloud account, and on Google Container Engine (GKE) Kubernetes is configured to be able to access these resources by ID, and can mount this type of volume into your Pod.

If you're not running Kubernetes on GKE, then you can't really mount a Google Cloud volume into your pod: the resources need to be managed by the same provider.